# Is there any relationship between primitive rings and semi-prime rings? If yes, then what?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I am reading the book "rings with involution" by I.N.Herstein. it is written on page no. 15 paragraph no. 3 that R is primitive ring so it has no nilpotent ideals. This made me think so.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A right (or left) primitive ring is also prime, and hence semiprime.

To expand a bit, let's talk about four classes of rings:

[image]

Comment: And what about left primitive ring, sir.

Comment: @Rattanverma Obviously also prime (there is no reason for the statement to be side dependent.)

Comment: Sir, where can I found it's proof? Do you have any?

Comment: Let $M$ be a faithful simple right $R$ module and suppose $A$ and $B$ are nonzero right ideals such that $AB=\{0\}$.  $MA$ is a submodule of $M$, so either $MA=M$ or $MA=\{0\}$. The second case is excluded since $M$ is faithful. Similarly, $MB=M$. But $M=MB=MAB=M\{0\}=0$, a contradiction. Therefore no such $A,B$ exist, and $R$ is prime.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot sir.